# Exception with Boxview.LinearGradientBrush

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

When I try to insert a BoxView with a GradientBackground this exception is thrown. In the c # code I have inserted the Flag, but it is not enough. How could I solve?

> System.TypeLoadException: 'Could not resolve type with token 0100009c from typeref (expected class 'Xamarin.Forms.GradientStop' in assembly 'Xamarin.Forms.Core, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null')'

**XAML code**

```
<BoxView>
      <BoxView.Background>
          <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,0">
               <GradientStop Color="Gray" Offset="0" />
               <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="1.0" />
          </LinearGradientBrush>
     </BoxView.Background>
</BoxView>
```

**c# code**

```
     public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Device.SetFlags(new[] { "Brush_Experimental" });
    }
```

Comment: call `SetFlags` in your App class, not your Page

Comment: keep giving me the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you should set flags in your App class or AppDelegate/MainActivity respectively.

(**Official Documentation on Flags and how to opt in**)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/internals/experimental-flags

Try updating your Xamarin.Forms NuGet package in the package manager, an older version has often been the cause of similar problems for me.

Also try cleaning and rebuilding your solution. I have created a video on how to opt in to Xamarin Experimental features, if all else fails try watching it and catching a difference between your project and my sample project:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W008ZlCjEZ8

Comment: I solved it by updating the Nuget packages! Thanks a lot!

Comment: nice, thats the problem a lot of the time, its usually set to 4.6 when it should be 4.8